# How to send multiple array with array of objects send to android

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I am using this code this format shows Invalid JSON Please tell me any code of android

```
 Format:-->
    {
     "supplyType":"O",
     "subSupplyType":"1",
     "subSupplyDesc":"TESTDESCRIPTION",
     "docType": "BIL", 
     "docNo": "18-86"
        "itemList": [{
      "productName": "Wheat",
      "productDesc": "Wheat",
      "hsnCode": 84,
      "quantity": 10,
      "qtyUnit": "BOX",
      "cgstRate": 0,
      "sgstRate": 0,
      "igstRate": 12,
      "cessRate": 0,
      "cessAdvol": 0,
      "taxableAmount":5609889
     },
     {
      "productName": "Wheat",
      "productDesc": "Wheat",
      "hsnCode": 84,
      "quantity": 10,
      "qtyUnit": "BOX",
      "cgstRate": 0,
      "sgstRate": 0,
      "igstRate": 12,
      "cessRate": 0,
      "cessAdvol": 0,
      "taxableAmount":5609889
     }]
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I am asking that how to send data in this format to android to server using volley  # Vladyslav Matviienko

Comment: just send it as string

Answer (score 0):

Check this -

```
 {
     "supplyType":"O",
     "subSupplyType":"1",
     "subSupplyDesc":"TESTDESCRIPTION",
     "docType": "BIL", 
     "docNo": "18-86",
        "itemList": [
          {
      "productName": "Wheat",
      "productDesc": "Wheat",
      "hsnCode": 84,
      "quantity": 10,
      "qtyUnit": "BOX",
      "cgstRate": 0,
      "sgstRate": 0,
      "igstRate": 12,
      "cessRate": 0,
      "cessAdvol": 0,
      "taxableAmount":5609889
     },
     {
      "productName": "Wheat",
      "productDesc": "Wheat",
      "hsnCode": 84,
      "quantity": 10,
      "qtyUnit": "BOX",
      "cgstRate": 0,
      "sgstRate": 0,
      "igstRate": 12,
      "cessRate": 0,
      "cessAdvol": 0,
      "taxableAmount":5609889
     }
     ]
    }
```

Comment: any code how to send data in this format android to server ?

Comment: So,Do you want to fetch this data from server and to show in android application?@kuldeep sharma

Comment: No, I am not fetching  I am sending the data @Dhanshri